# different homepage for annonymous users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I have a requirement in which home page of my site is personalisable by the end user (I have page where all the webparts are listed with Add/Remove functionality) so that each user can add Or remove a webpart dynamically from his personalisable scope from home page.  Things are working fine but now we have  to give a annonymous access to our site.

Is there any way to set the homepage webparts - By Admin to set UI of the homepage (add webparts) for annonymous user using OOB screen?  I have tried the target audience but its not really works in the way I need.  Is there any way to reuse the existing homepage .  or  is there any way to make a different welcome page for annonymous users?

Comment: Do you speak about personalization of "my sites" homepage or about homepage of SPSiteCollection? If second, you can simply make web part redirector for anonimouse user. It will redirect anonimouse users for special for anonimouse users page.

Comment: Hey IAfanasov i am looking for something like a different site welcome page for annonymous rather than redirecting user every time he lands on homepage .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your Master page to have specific zones that apply to anonymous vs. authenticated users.

Check out Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl and AnonymousTemplate.